# MonoGame ContentManager class?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have recently got into c# with XNA and am just making the transition to MonoGame since I've read that XNA is no longer supported. With that said I have come across a problem in MonoGame that I didn't have with XNA when attempting to make a Load() method for a Sprite class in my program. The way I used to do it in XNA is as follows:

```
public void Load(ContentManager content)
{
    content.Load<Texture2D>(AssetName);
}
```

Now the problem I have with MonoGame is that I cannot seem to reference ContentManager in my Sprite class. The class has all the 'using Microsoft.Xna.Framework' that my Game1 class has, and nothing in my code is static so I don't understand why I cannot reference ContentManager, since it is not recognised when I try and put it in the Load(). Is there a different way to do this in MonoGame, or am I not referencing it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I don't see the issue right away, but I'll try to help:

- You have probably tried right-click/resolve already, but it's worth saying it anyways.
- Reminder that Loading content in Monogame is different than using XNA. You've to use the build-in pipeline tool and transfer the content over there, don't forget to build it everytime when uploading a new texture.
- There has been no changes to the Content.RootDirectory?

Just making some heads-up to be sure you've done that. and hopefully this will help you out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've referenced the `MonoGame.Framework.dll` or NuGet package there's nothing special about the code. It should look something like this:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace YourGameProject
{
    public class Sprite
    {
        public string AssetName { get; set; }

        public void Load(ContentManager content)
        {
            content.Load<Texture2D>(AssetName);
        }
    }
}
```

I just wrote that code in my own project and it compiles. If it's not working for you there must be something else wrong.

Comment: Damn, that's pretty much what I've wrote and it just doesn't seem to recognise ContentManager in my Sprite class. I'll get a fresh copy of VS and MonoGame and see if it works. Thanks anyways though!